# Can covariance of A be used to calculate A'*A?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, covariance

I am doing a benchmarking test in python on different ways to calculate A'*A, with A being a N x M matrix. One of the fastest ways was to use `numpy.dot()`.

I was curious if I can obtain the same result using `numpy.cov()` (which gives the covariance matrix) by somehow varying the weights or by somehow pre-processing the A matrix ? But I had no success. Does anyone know if there is any relation between the product A'*A and covariance of A, where A is a matrix with N  rows/observations and M columns/variables?

Comment: ```np.dot()``` is the fastest (for dense arrays; uses BLAS) if you need a real matrix-multiplication. No need to analyze other approaches. Why are you interested in this?

Comment: thanks for your answer. The researcher under whom I am working asked me find whether matrix multiplication can be done by `numy.cov()` and `numpy.corrcoef()` and benchmark their timings compared to other methods in python.

Comment: I think this is a math (linear algebra) problem rather than a numpy problem. You are asking whether there is a equivalence relationship between A.T*A with some transformation of covariance matrix.

Comment: thank you. I have edited my question and tags a bit.

Comment: I have edited the python/numpy tags back in. Although this is mostly a general math question (which is off-topic on SO, btw) it is also about how to do that in numpy specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`cov` source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2883-L3089). Near the end of the function it does this:

```
c = dot(X, X_T.conj())
```

Which is basically the dot product you want to perform. However, there are all kinds of other operations: checking inputs, subtracting the mean, normalization, ...

In short, `np.cov` will never ever be faster than `np.dot(A.T, A)` because internally it contains exactly that operation.

That said - the [covariance matrix is computed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices) as

[image]

Or in Python:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10, 3)

m = np.mean(a, axis=0, keepdims=True)
x = np.dot((a - m).T, a - m) / (a.shape[0] - 1)

y = np.cov(a.T)

assert np.allclose(x, y)  # check they are equivalent
```

As you can see, the covariance matrix is equivalent to the raw dot product if you subtract the mean of each variable and divide the result by the number of samples (minus one).